# How to get gulp.series to run two tasks that run successfully when run individually?

Tags: gulp

I have a gulp 4 file that contains a watch task and a SyncBrowsers task. These two tasks run successfully when run independently. however then in a default task with a gulp.series I get no response. The task appears to hang. Can someone explain why this is and how to fix is?

I've followed the the API suggestions from gulpjs.com for the beginning walk through and also for the series task. I have also investigated the browserSync documentation from https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/minimal-browsersync-setup-with-gulp4.md. This example does a similar process as I am doing and works correctly.

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
let uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
let prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
let gulpif = require('gulp-if');
let nano = require('gulp-cssnano');
let sourcemap = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
let del = require('del');
let runSequence = require('run-sequence');
let pug = require('gulp-pug');

const server = browserSync.create();
server.watch('wwwroot/*.html').on("change", server.reload);
//build tasks

function clean() {
    return del('wwwroot');

}


//development tasks
function SyncBrowsers(cb) {
    server.init({
        server:{
            baseDir: 'wwwroot',
            index: 'index.html'
        },
        port: 3002
    });
    cb();
}

function fsass() {
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/css'))
}

function pugtohtml() {
    return gulp.src('app/pug/**/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug({
        pretty:true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/'))
}


function watch (cb) {
    gulp.watch(['app/scss/**/*.scss','app/*.html','app/js/**/*.js','app/pug/**/*.pug'],gulp.series(fsass, pugtohtml));
    cb();   
}

function build (){
    return gulp.series(clean, pugtohtml, fsass, fonts)
}

function defaults(cb){
   gulp.series(SyncBrowsers,watch);
   cb();
}

//run tasks
exports.build = build;

exports.default = defaults;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.pugtohtml = pugtohtml;
exports.fsass = fsass;
exports.clean = clean;
exports.SyncBrowsers = SyncBrowsers;
```

Comment: Does it work when you do `exports.default = gulp.series(SyncBrowsers, watch);`?

Comment: @TheDancingCode thanks for your comment. Yes it works. any idea why putting the series inside a function causes the process to stop?